# Paypal Express prepopulate email address

Tags: php, paypal, express, checkout

Thanks to some some other questions on here, I've opted to use the PayPal Express Checkout functionality with PHP. It is pretty much working except the payer's email isn't transferring to PayPal to pre-populate that field. I've gotten billing address and phone to work. What am I missing? The snippet of code is:

```
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP='.urlencode($_SESSION['zip']).
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM='.urlencode($_SESSION['phone']).
'&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL=jsmith01@example.com'.
'&NOSHIPPING=1'.
```

Obviously the email address will be a variable, but hard coded it for testing purposes. What am I missing?

This code goes to  SetExpressCheckout, which directs buyer to Paypal to enter billing info/sign in and complete purchase. They are not redirected back to my site for review and to complete the order, so there is no DoExpressCheckout call.

Thanks for any input and help.

Comment: I'll preface this with saying I have no idea how the API works, but I thought I'd search for you.  Based on the classic API, `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL` isn't a valid field name.  `EMAIL` is though, is that what you're wanting? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 0):

The "PAYMENTREQUEST" fields are returned by Paypal - you don't use them on the SetExpressCheckout.

Use the **EMAIL** field..

(Optional) Email address of the buyer as entered during checkout. PayPal uses this value to pre-fill the PayPal membership sign-up portion on the PayPal pages.
Character length and limitations: 127 single-byte alphanumeric characters